# JavaFX program not displaying scene

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX program that is supposed to be rendering a certain layout with the following code:

RealEstateSearcher.java (starts the application):

```
public class RealEstateSearcher extends Application {
private RealEstateModel myModel;
private Stage mainStage;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    MainStageContainer.setStage(primaryStage, "Real Estate Searcher");
    mainStage = MainStageContainer.getInstance();
    mainStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    try {
        myModel = new RealEstateModel();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    WindowPosition.placeCenter(mainStage);
    mainStage.show();
}
}
```

RealEstateModel.java (controls the application logic, supposed to set the Scene on the Stage):

```
public class RealEstateModel {
private HouseList houses;
private Stage myStage;
private Scene myScene;
private View realEstateView;
public RealEstateModel() {
    houses = new HouseList("houses.txt");
    myStage = MainStageContainer.getInstance();
    createAndShowRealEstateView();
}
public void createAndShowRealEstateView() {
    realEstateView = new RealEstateView(this);
    myScene = new Scene(realEstateView);
    myStage.setScene(myScene);
    myStage.sizeToScene();
    WindowPosition.placeCenter(myStage);
}
}
```

RealEstateView.java (the View I am trying to render):

```
public class RealEstateView extends View {
private RealEstateModel myModel;
private TextField minPrice;
private TextField maxPrice;
private TextField minArea;
private TextField maxArea;
private TextField minBeds;
private TextField maxBeds;
private TextField resultsBox;
private Button searchButton;
private Button nextButton;
private Button resetButton;
public RealEstateView(RealEstateModel m) {
    super("Real Estate Searcher");
    myModel = m;
    VBox container = new VBox(10);
    container.setPadding(new Insets(15, 5, 5, 5));
    container.getChildren().add(createTitle());
    container.getChildren().add(createFormContents());
}
private Node createTitle() {
    Text titleText = new Text("Real Estate Listings");
    titleText.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));
    titleText.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
    titleText.setFill(Color.DARKGREEN);
    return titleText;
}
private VBox createFormContents() {
    VBox mainContainer = new VBox(10);
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));
    Label minPrLabel = new Label("Minimum price: ");
    grid.add(minPrLabel, 0, 0);
    minPrice = new TextField();
    minPrice.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            processAction(e);
        }
    });
    grid.add(minPrice, 1, 0);
    Label maxPrLabel = new Label("Maximum price: ");
    grid.add(maxPrLabel, 0, 1);
    maxPrice = new TextField();
    maxPrice.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            processAction(e);
        }
    });
    grid.add(maxPrice, 1, 1);
    Label minArLabel = new Label("Minimum area: ");
    grid.add(minArLabel, 0, 2);
    minArea = new TextField();
    minArea.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            processAction(e);
        }
    });
    grid.add(minArea, 1, 2);
    Label maxArLabel = new Label("Maximum area: ");
    grid.add(maxArLabel, 0, 3);
    maxArea = new TextField();
    maxArea.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            processAction(e);
        }
    });
    grid.add(maxArea, 1, 3);
    Label minBdLabel = new Label("Minimum beds: ");
    grid.add(minBdLabel, 0, 4);
    minBeds = new TextField();
    minBeds.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            processAction(e);
        }
    });
    grid.add(minBeds, 1, 4);
    Label maxBdLabel = new Label("Maximum beds: ");
    grid.add(maxBdLabel, 0, 5);
    maxBeds = new TextField();
    maxBeds.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            processAction(e);
        }
    });
    grid.add(maxBeds, 1, 5);
    Label resultsLabel = new Label("Chosen Home: ");
    grid.add(resultsLabel, 0, 7);
    resultsBox = new TextField();
    resultsBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            processAction(e);
        }
    });
    grid.add(resultsBox, 1, 7);
    searchButton = new Button("Find my dream house!");
    searchButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            processAction(e);
        }
    });
    grid.add(searchButton, 0, 8);
    nextButton = new Button("Not my dream -- find me another!");
    nextButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            processAction(e);
        }
    });
    grid.add(nextButton, 1, 8);
    mainContainer.getChildren().add(grid);
    resetButton = new Button("Reset");
    resetButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            processAction(e);
        }
    });
    mainContainer.getChildren().add(resetButton);
    return mainContainer;
}
public void processAction(Event evt) {
    int minPrEntered = minPrice.getText() == null ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(minPrice.getText());
    int maxPrEntered = maxPrice.getText() == null ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : Integer.parseInt(maxPrice.getText());
    int minArEntered = minArea.getText() == null ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(minArea.getText());
    int maxArEntered = maxArea.getText() == null ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : Integer.parseInt(maxArea.getText());
    int minBdEntered = minBeds.getText() == null ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(minBeds.getText());
    int maxBdEntered = maxBeds.getText() == null ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : Integer.parseInt(maxBeds.getText());
}
public void updateState(String key, Object value) {

}
}
```

Why is this code rendering a blank screen and not the layout I created?

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the error.
In the constructor of the RealEstateView class, I had to add the following line at the end to add the layout to the scene:

```
getChildren().add(container);
```